# Comparing migration statistics of the same city

Tags: hypothesis-testing, demography

I've got a city with 12 districts and I've got a table of the number the people who moved within the city to other districts, which looks roughly like this, but the numbers are just for illustration:

```
to\from 1   2   3   4   ... 12
1       -   100 200 100     300
2       200 -   100 300     100
3       250 100 -   100     300
...
12      200 100 200 100     -
```

Also, I have a different source which also maps the migration process somehow, but they have measured a smaller number of overall mitigations, because they didn't extrapolate their measurements to the whole population, e.g. like this:

```
to\from 1   2   3   4   ... 12
1       -   1   2   2       2
2       2   -   1   2       1
3       2   1   -   1       2
...
12      2   2   1   1       -
```

Which tests are useful to compare these kind of measurements? I think that looking at a PCA of these tables (and their transpositions) might give an idea if these measurements are different, but I'm not sure which kind of test should be used to compare these kind of measurements. Would a Chi-Squared test work in this setting?